# How to skip over auto-inserted matching chars in vim insert mode?

Tags: vim

When I'm in VIM insert mode, it wonderfully adds matching end characters. E.g. if I type `"` it will add another `"` immediately after the cursor. Similarly for parenthesis, braces etc. when programming.

How can I quickly skip over the inserted character, while staying in insert mode? The best I've found is to use the forward arrow key, but that's not conveniently located.

Accordingly, I either type the closing character, or I `<esc>li` (*exit insert mode, move right one character, re-enter insert mode*). This reduces the convenience of the auto-insertion quite dramatically, so I figure I'm missing something obvious.

*(Note, for convenience I'm using the handy [SPF13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) curated collection of plugins and running MacVIM.  Edit: [This is](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) the autoclose script providing the matching.)*

Comment: Because you're using that distribution, you don't even know which plugin provides this! Better start from scratch, and learn each plugin. -- Typically, you just continue typing (the text within), and then type the concluding character; the plugin should make the cursor move over instead of inserting it again.

Comment: "When I'm in VIM insert mode, it wonderfully adds matching end characters." Everything is wrong, here, except Ingo's comment.

Comment: Ingo is absolutely right. don't use any vim "distribution"! You don't know what are vim built-in features with those dist. worse is, you don't know what are the causes if you had problem. If you love those dists, don't ask here, try to get support on the dist-community or issue-tracker.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Yes, I'm trying to **skip** typing the concluding character. That's the point of the question. Indeed, as you and I both said, I can then continue, but it sort of defeats the purpose, no?  As for not using distros, sorry, I just ain't that pure. I've been using vi[m] for 30 yrs now and having a packaged distro is just too dang convenient. If I had to keep up with every plugin change over those years... ugh! Who has the time! Marking down the question because it offends some _purity and essence of our natural fluids_ is nice, but it sidesteps the issue :)

Comment: I downvoted your question because both your issue and your incapability to solve it are caused by your lazyness: you don't care about your configuration enough to even know what provides that feature and find yourself helpless when something undesirable happens because you have no idea what does what in your "handy" distribution. If you were not so lazy, you would have already read the documentation of the autoclosing plugin and find out a solution or workaround. But, you let someone install something somewhere on your machine and you are at loss.

Comment: @romainl <Yawn>. You speculate about my steps before posting this,  my motivations, my capabilities, and then you present it as fact, as if you know me. Oh, hang on, I forgot, this is the internet. Nevermind. (/me notices the _Don't feed the trolls._ sign.)

Answer (score 4):

There's basically *no* way to get out of an autoclosed pair that doesn't involve *pressing at least one key*.

The standard mechanism provided by all the autoclosing plugins is simple: type the closing character. You can also press `<Right>` or, if you are at the end of the line, `<End>`.

Maybe your plugin gives you another mechanism but you'll have to find out for yourself.

Whatever key you press, you'll still do *at the very least* exactly the same amount of typing as you'd do without autoclosing.

Autoclosing is *not* about saving typing, the only practical use of that feature is to *prevent unmatched pairs*. That's all and, I think, the "obvious" thing you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for that useful explanation. I'm not trying to avoid _any_ key, just the often obscure matching punctiuation key. Some keys are easier to type than others after all. As there are various control keys in insert mode (per `:help ins-special-keys`) I thought I might be missing some skip to end of punctuation key that my research hadn't turned up. Apparently not. I'll leave this up a while longer to see if someone else has any (hopefully less perjorative) thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a SPF13 and don't know which plugins brought the mapping. There are two things that we can do

1) I usually <kbd>esc</kbd> followed by `A`. This will kept you in insert mode after the closed character **if it is the last character**. I usually prefer this over the second one.

2) You can circumvent the automatic closing by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> before the character, for instance `"`. This will not autoclose the corresponding character and you are responsible for the closing.